# The server content appears to be out of date. Would you like to build and deploy the project first?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, tabular, cube

i created cube in analysis services in VS 2017
my problem is i cant process .cube file to sql server
this is error message i get

> The server content appears to be out of date.  Would you like to build
>   and deploy the project first?

i have analysis services server opened in background
in services both analysis services server and sql server browser are active
i would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: I assume you /have/ built and deployed the project? What happens if you do so (again, if necessary)? (Just for the avoidance of any doubt, the fact that the SSAS server is running doesn't mean VS is talking to it in any way. Apologies if you were clear on that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the definition of the cube and/or database on your database server are different from what is in your project in Visual Studio.   Meaning somebody made changes to one, but not the other.

You need to bring them into sync before you can process the cube from your Visual Studio project.

If you want to overwrite what's on the server with what's in the project, just build and deploy the project.

If you want to overwrite your project with what's on the server, you'll need to generate a new project by importing from your database, and use it to replace your existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i solved it 
in deployment settings i  set server destination as servername/user instead of servername

Comment: So, is the real answer here to check for error messages?